# C# 8.0 and .net 3.0

Tags: .net-core-3.0, c#-8.0

```
using (var db = new Northwind())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Categories and how many products they have:");
                IQueryable<Category> cats = db.Categories.Include(c => c.Products);
                foreach (Category c in cats)
                {
                    WriteLine($"{c.CategoryName} has {c.Products.Count} products.");
                }
            }
```

I am reading c # 8.0 .net core 3.0 by Mark J. Price, but I went to Working with Databases Using Entity Framework Core and I got an error during the query. The connection to the database is connected successfully.
The error is generated when I output cats (System.ArgumentException: 'Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.'). I cannot solve this problem, please help me.

Comment: You haven't provided sufficient context. As written, your query will work assuming everything else is correct in your database configuration

Comment: I can't find the configuration file in the console app.

Comment: The `Northwind` class should contain code similar to `optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString)`. Find that code and check/correct the connectionString.

Comment: thanks, i fixed the error, connectionString not found path kkkkk